# Access cookie information from JOOMLA Article

Tags: joomla

My aim is to show the text - "Welcome username"

The username info is stored in the cookie. How do i access that cookie information to show it up in the Joomla! Article.

I would like to know if there's a way to do this without creating a module.

Thanks

Comment: Where does the username come from? Is the user logged in? Then there should be no need to store the username in a cookie IMO, which is not a good practice security wise

Comment: I get it from the URL and set the cookie manually. Security is not a problem. Its not exactly the username. Just an example i used here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the cookie from the article because cannot insert PHP code in the article content, it is stripped by the editor.

But you can create module which is quite easy all you have to use is:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
echo 'Welcome ' . $user->name;
```

and add this module to your article using `{loadposition myposition}`

If you want to use the cookie you have set you can use:

```
echo 'Welcome ' . JRequest::getString('username', '', 'cookie');
```

Also you can have a look at this blank module, it;s good start:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules/3668

Answer (score 0):

Without creating any module, you can also directly use php code in joomla article by using some extensions as follows:

[http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/....custom-code-in-content/4470](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470)

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/1023/details

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/use-javascript-or-php-in-a-joomla-article/